# Is there any tool/library/api (or anything at all) to categorize youtube videos

Tags: python, web-scraping, filter, youtube-api, categorization

I am trying to categorize videos on Youtube e.g. Entertainment, Nature, Educational, etc etc. Because many Youtube channels don´t use helpful hashtags, any video would be hard to categorize. I am trying to create a filter where I watch YouTube videos only based on my mood /need and categorizing them would help. Is there any automatic way?

Comment: In addition to [@takiniteasy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7831047/takiniteasy) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73074030/7123660), you can get the [`tags`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.tags[]), [`categoryId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.categoryId) and [`topicDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#topicDetails) of a YouTube video by fetching https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,topicDetails&id=VIDEO_ID&key=API_KEY

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a YouTube API already that has this. Read through the documentation bellow for more details

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories

Comment: Please refrain from posting link-only answers (they aren't valid answers). Also, the question itself is off-topic.